# python resizing a Qpainter

Tags: python, pyqt, pyqt4, qpainter

i have tried to change the size of my Qpainter and i can't figure out how could someone help here is my code i have looked online and i cant figure it out since the code i need is embedded in a shit tone of other code that is not needed thanks for your help.

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize, QTimer
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication,QGraphicsRectItem , QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget, QIcon, QLabel, QPainter, QPixmap, QMessageBox, QAction, QKeySequence, QFont, QFontMetrics, QMovie
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class UIWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UIWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(QSize(400, 450))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        painter.drawPixmap(self.rect(), QPixmap("Images\Image.png"))
        painter.move(0,0)
        painter.resize(950,270)




class MainWindow(QMainWindow,):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(490, 200, 950, 620)
        self.setFixedSize(950, 620)
        self.startUIWindow()
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('Images\Logo.png'))

    def startUIWindow(self):
        self.Window = UIWindow(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("pythonw")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.Window)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: @eyllanesc i am trying to make my image appear at the vary top of the program not in the center and all distorted

Comment: @eyllanesc the image i am using is already a 950 X 270 pixels and is still showing distorted on the program.

Comment: @eyllanesc this is what my image is showing up like

Comment: @eyllanesc yes i want the image to stay at 950 x 270 but i would like the image not to be squished and at the top of the program

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The drawPixmap function requires as the first parameter the rectangle where it is to be drawn, ie (0, 0, width, height)

```
def paintEvent(self, event):
    painter = QPainter(self)
    pixmap = QPixmap("Images\Image.png")
    painter.drawPixmap(QRect(0, 0, pixmap.width(), pixmap.height()), pixmap)
```

Complete Code:

```
import sys
import os
from PyQt4.QtCore import QSize, QTimer, QRect
from PyQt4.QtGui import QApplication,QGraphicsRectItem , QMainWindow, QPushButton, QWidget, QIcon, QLabel, QPainter, QPixmap, QMessageBox, QAction, QKeySequence, QFont, QFontMetrics, QMovie
from PyQt4 import QtGui


class UIWindow(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(UIWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.resize(QSize(400, 450))

    def paintEvent(self, event):
        painter = QPainter(self)
        pixmap = QPixmap("Images\Image.png")
        painter.drawPixmap(QRect(0, 0, pixmap.width(), pixmap.height()), pixmap)


class MainWindow(QMainWindow,):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setGeometry(490, 200, 950, 620)
        self.setFixedSize(950, 620)
        self.startUIWindow()

    def startUIWindow(self):
        self.Window = UIWindow(self)
        self.setWindowTitle("pythonw")
        self.setCentralWidget(self.Window)
        self.show()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```